# Brew Error: No available formula with the name "–force"

Tags: homebrew

Tried removing node with brew, got an error:

```
$ brew uninstall –force node                         

Error: No available formula with the name "–force".
FAIL
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall any package with brew use `remove` instead of `uninstall`. Also place `--force` flag after the actual formula name **node**:

```
brew remove node --force
```